# How can I change self.view constraint in autolayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to move the y position (top constraint) of self.view programmatically. But i am not able to found the any constraint that can i change the run time

```
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -59, self.view.frame,size.width, self.view.frame,size.height);
```

Something like this but with constraint?

Comment: where have you been stuck, honestly? have you tried to change your constraints' `constant` values, perhaps? I don't see any attempt here...

Comment: I have 2 textfield at the center. so i want to move up when keyboard ups. so i thought to move self.view up. to change constraint i need the top constraint objects but how can i found for the self.view constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a new `UIView` and add your `textfield` inside the new UIView. Add the new `UIView` inside main view (`self.view`). Add `Constraint` for new `UIView`.

now you can change new `UIView` `constraint` programmatically,

```
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * topConstraint;
```

**or**

```
    NSArray * arrConstarint=self.view.constraints;
    for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraint in arrConstarint)
    {
        if (constraint.firstAttribute==NSLayoutAttributeTop) {
            // if problem then add constraint.firstItem or constraint.secondAttribute etc
            constraint.constant=-59;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never move the view of your view controller. Setting the frame of a view is the responsibility of the superview. For a view controller this means, positioning `self.view` is the responsibility of the surrounding view controller (e.g. the `UINavigationController`).

Instead when trying to move the content so that your keyboard does not hide any content, you should move the content inside your view to the correct position. However, keep in mind that, as of iOS8 and custom keyboards, a keyboard can practically have any height, so you can never guarantee that all your subviews are visible on screen. Most of the time - there might be exceptions - it is a better approach to move your text fields inside a `UIScrollView` and change the scroll view's `contentOffset` so that the current first responder (the text field currently being edited) is visible.